# An uncaught Exception was encountered,,,

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Model_benda
>
> Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/latihan_ci/system/core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 348
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/latihan_ci/application/controllers/Barang.php
>   Line: 8
>   Function: model
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/latihan_ci/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

//THIS MY CONTROLLER

```
<?php
    /**
     * 
     */
    class Barang extends CI_Controller  {

        function index() {
            $this->load->model('model_benda');
            $judul = "Daftar Barang";
            $data['judul'] = $judul;
            $data['barang'] = $this->model_benda->list_barang(); 
            $this->load->view('list_barang', $data);    
        }
    }
?>
```

//AND THIS MY MODEL

```
<?php

    class model_benda extends CI_Model  {

        function list_barang() {
            $barang = array('sepatu','jam_tangan','robot');
            return $barang
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The name of the file containing the `model_benda` class should be `model_benda.php`.

Comment: And we have seen this question once already today!

Comment: additionally it should be uppercase first letter in the model name `Model_benda`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, hopefully it will be useful and increase my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter models must have an uppercase first character so

```
class model_benda extends CI_Model  {
```

should be

```
class Model_benda extends CI_Model  {
```

You do not have to use uppercase first when loading the model so `$this->load->model('model_benda');` will work just fine.

The uppercase first rule also applies to the file name, so the model file must be `Model_benda.php`